# Robotframework - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_parent'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Iam working on the robotframework, i want to highlight the element on the page below is the code
i am getting the error

"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_parent' "

Below is the code,

```
import time

def highlight(element):
    """Highlights (blinks) a Selenium Webdriver element"""
    driver = element._parent
    def apply_style(s):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                              element, s)
    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
    time.sleep(.3)
    apply_style(original_style)
```

**Common.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary   15.0    5.0
Library    OperatingSystem
Library           highlight.py
Resource    ../LoginPage/LoginKW.robot

*** Variables ***
${URL}           https://www.involve.me/

*** Keywords ***
Start
    ${options}=  Evaluate        sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Log To Console                                 ${options}
    Create WebDriver    Chrome      chrome_options=${options}
    Go To          ${URL}
    ${handles}=  Get Window Handles
    Maximize Browser Window
    Verify Current URL
    ${SCREEN_TEXTS}  Read Json    ../../TestData/Involve_Test.json
    Set Global Variable    ${SCREEN_TEXTS}

Read Json
    [Documentation]    The function, with its' own keyword reads the json files.
    [Arguments]        ${file_path}
    ${JSONContent}     Get File     ${file_path}
    ${page}=           Evaluate        json.loads("""${JSONContent}""")    json
    [Return]           ${page}

Close My Browser
    Sleep  2s
    Close All Browsers

Click For Element
    [Arguments]                         ${element}
    Highlight                           ${element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       ${element}
    Click Element                       ${element}

Input For Text
    [Arguments]                         ${element}      ${input}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       ${element}
    Highlight                           ${element}
    Input Text                          ${element}      ${input}
```

**LoginTC.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Test Case Login
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Resource            ../../PageObjects/LoginPage/LoginKW.robot
Resource            ../../PageObjects/Common/common.robot
Test Setup        Start  # Suitw Setup will run only once
Test Teardown      common.Close My Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Test Login
    sleep    3s
    Click Cookie
    Click On Link Login
    Enter Email                          xxxxxyyyyzzz@gmail.com
    Enter Password                       abcdefghijk3Only
    Click On Sign in button
    Is Text Displayed     ${SCREEN_TEXTS["ws_page_title"]}
```

When i run the script getting the error.

## (venv) C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\InvolvemeRobotFramework\TestCases\Login> robot LoginTC1.robot

## LoginTC1 :: Test Case Login

Test Login                                                            <selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x041902B0>

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61649/devtools/browser/4914f52f-47f6-4632-a776-02045dda890c
https://www.involve.me/
..F.....[28328:8120:0508/220557.776:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [22:05:57.777] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connec
tion: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Test Login                                                            | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_parent'

Can someone please help me

Comment: What are you passing to `highlight` keyword? Because RF complains about str, I would guess you are passing XPath or similar as a string. You can debug it by logging the type and contents of the `element` variable. You can also try TRACE loglevel with `-L TRACE`.

Comment: yes, it's printing the xpath value, 
16:31:52.241 INFO Value:::    xpath://div[@id='cookiescript_accept'] 
16:31:52.243 FAIL AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_parent'                                                    to make this work it has to print like this                                                                                                              <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="98f5eab03abb5d613ecc7d12fd2849f3", element="a36621db-6a34-4ba0-9c82-45f68904d436")>
 how to print that in robot framework ?

Comment: Thank you for the info. It looks like the keyword `Click Cookie` fails. Somewhere in that keyword, you might have this keyword: `Highlight    //div[@id='cookiescript_accept']`. You cannot pass XPath to highlight function because it requires an element. You need to have something like this before: `${element}=    Get WebElement     //div[@id='cookiescript_accept']` and pass `${element}` to the Highlight keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pekka your solution worked for me, yes I need to pass web element,

Answer (score 0):

Change 'element' to 'self' because your class lack a constructor